# Simplest way of using Hibernate Sessions

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm coaching a student project which uses hibernate as a persistence layer. From my projects at work I'm already quite familiar with hibernate and can use it with few 'troubles'. But with this project we have constantly problem with sessions, stale objects and and 'object was loaded from a different session'-errors.

So what I am looking for the simplest possible way to use sessions:

Ideal would be:

- Sessions can be fetched from anywhere
- It shouldn't matter whether or not a given object was loaded with session A and then updated with Session B

Its a single-process GUI application. The current setting for current_session_context_class is thread. But I use a static field for the session variable (which I think causes some of my troubles) and only fetch it ONCE.

Thanks for your assistance!

Cheers,
Reto

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're not teaching ORM, the understanding of *why* these errors happen isn't part of the knowledge the students are supposed to come away with etc etc etc and you just want Hibernate to work as a database wrapper so they can get data to use while learning other things.

This is probably your best bet:

```
StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
```

A stateless session is effectively "auto-commit mode for ORM" and as close to raw-JDBC wrapper as hibernate gets.  No Sessions, no L1 caches, no persistence context.  Just SQL/HQL that returns objects.

Comment: to your question: yap thats the goal. They are exposed to these concepts much too early. but anyway, its kinda sad that hibernate has 1001 way to do does things, and that the documentation doesn't show these steps of improvement (together with their limitations and requirements) more clearly. I see that there's a big way between a stateless session and a fully container-managed transaction provider. etc. :) but still, it feels much too complicated for simple things. anyway, thanks for the hint!